# AzCopy Unknown /source command

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I have the following script currently:

```
$azPath = "C:\temp"
Set-Location $azPath

$StorageAccountName = "#"
$StorageAccountKey = "#"
$ContainerName = "sqlbackups"

$SourceFolder = "C:\temp"

$DestURL = "https://$StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/$ContainerName"
$Result = .\AzCopy.exe /source:$SourceFolder /dest:$DestURL /BlobType:block /destkey:$StorageAccountKey /Y
$Result
```

and I get the following error:

```
PS C:\temp> .\load-backups2.ps1
Error: unknown command "/source:C:\\temp" for "azcopy"
Run 'azcopy --help' for usage.

unknown command "/source:C:\\temp" for "azcopy"
```

I'm wondering if anyone could see what I'm doing wrong here>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, I suppose your `azcopy.exe` is located in the `C:\temp` folder.
To fix the issue, just remove the `.\` in the `$Result = .\AzCopy.exe /source:$SourceFolder /dest:$DestURL /BlobType:block /destkey:$StorageAccountKey /Y`.

It  should be `$Result = AzCopy.exe /source:$SourceFolder /dest:$DestURL /BlobType:block /destkey:$StorageAccountKey /Y`, but it will also upload the `azcopy.exe`, so I recommend you to move the `azcopy.exe` to another folder, like `C:\test`.

Then the script will be like as below, it works fine on my side.

```
$azPath = "C:\test"
Set-Location $azPath

$StorageAccountName = "#"
$StorageAccountKey = "#"
$ContainerName = "sqlbackups"

$SourceFolder = "C:\temp"

$DestURL = "https://$StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/$ContainerName"
$Result = AzCopy.exe /source:$SourceFolder /dest:$DestURL /BlobType:block /destkey:$StorageAccountKey /Y
```

[image]

**Update:**

In my previous reply, I use `AzCopy.exe` directly, but actually I have installed the `AzCopy v8.1` in my PC, and I have set it to the system environment variable. So the result is for `v8.1`. I suppose you are using `AzCopy v10`, if I use  `AzCopy v10`, I can reproduce your issue, you may need to try [`AzCopy v8.1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy), it works. You could follow the steps below.

1.Download the [`AzCopy v8.1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy), install it, the default path will be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy\`, I use the default path.

2.Set the system environment variable `Path` with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy\`, save it. Details see this [link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

[image]

3.Then open a new powershell session, try the command. No need to `Set-Location`, because we have set the environment variable.

```
$StorageAccountName = "#"
$StorageAccountKey = "#"
$ContainerName = "sqlbackups"

$SourceFolder = "C:\temp"

$DestURL = "https://$StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/$ContainerName"
$Result = AzCopy.exe /source:$SourceFolder /dest:$DestURL /BlobType:block /destkey:$StorageAccountKey /Y
```

Comment: Thanks Joy, but I get this:

Suggestion [3,General]: The command AzCopy.exe was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell
 does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type ".\AzCopy.exe". Se
e "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

Comment: and if I re-add the .\ , I get Error: unknown command "/source:C:\\temp" for "azcopy"
Run 'azcopy --help' for usage.

unknown command "/source:C:\\temp" for "azcopy"

Answer (score 0):

```
$azPath = "C:\temp"
Set-Location $azPath




Try This:


$StorageAccountName = "#"
$StorageAccountKey = "#"
$ContainerName = "sqlbackups"

$SourceFolder = "C:\temp"

$DestURL = "https://$StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/$ContainerName"
$Result = .\AzCopy.exe copy "$SourceFolder" "$DestURL" --BlobType:blockblob --destkey:$StorageAccountKey /Y
$Result
```